# Не могу составить запрос к БД

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Есть таблица `hm_access_token` в которой 3 столбца: token, user_id, date_of_issue.

Делаю запрос `$wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE token=$token" )` В итоге получаю в ответ null. Если делаю запрос по user_id, ответ получаю верный: `$wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE user_id=$id" )`.

Значение token верное, копирую прямо из базы. Значение: `5223b090d5123d106512e4a9dc7f1b784449d6f25011a5aa37476935367d55f2`

В чем может быть проблема? Тип token: CHAR(64)

Comment: Добавить кавычки?

Comment: после запроса если он вернул null проверяйте на ошибки и выводите сообщения. И да, значение не в кавычках, вызывает синтаксическую ошибку (которую вы не видите, потому что на ошибки не проверяете). А вообще _никогда_ не подставляйте переменные в текст запроса, _всегда_ используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку значений http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anton Shchyrov вам предложил решение - добавить кавычки :

```
$wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE token='" . $token . "'");
```